# POST should not reload the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I have one problem, I realized a code in order to add in my db ids of article when on hover to make the article as read and the code below updates the page each time
There is my code (added datatype)

```
$('.newness').hover(
    function () {
        $(this).addClass('hover');
       newnessId = $(this).data('id');
       $.ajax({url:'/user_activities', method: 'POST', data: {user_activity:{activity_id: newnessId}},
           dataType: "script"
       })
    }
)
```

I think the problem is the 'POST'he refresh the page ...
Maybe the solution is to stack all ajax requests and execute the 'post' later but i don't know how to do that,
Sorry for my bad English

there is the logs :

```
Started POST "/user_activities.json" for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-05-25 14:31:49 +0200
Processing by UserActivitiesController#create as JSON
  Parameters: {"user_activity"=>{"activity_id"=>"3"}}
  User Load (1.6ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT $2  [["id", 2], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ /home/benjamin/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.0.rc1/lib/active_record/log_subscriber.rb:98
   (0.4ms)  BEGIN
  ↳ app/controllers/user_activities_controller.rb:12
  Activity Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "activities".* FROM "activities" WHERE "activities"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 3], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/controllers/user_activities_controller.rb:12
  UserActivity Exists (0.4ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "user_activities" WHERE "user_activities"."user_id" = $1 AND "user_activities"."activity_id" = $2 LIMIT $3  [["user_id", 2], ["activity_id", 3], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/controllers/user_activities_controller.rb:12
Started POST "/user_activities.json" for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-05-25 14:31:49 +0200
  UserActivity Create (6.7ms)  INSERT INTO "user_activities" ("activity_id", "user_id", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4) RETURNING "id"  [["activity_id", 3], ["user_id", 2], ["created_at", "2018-05-25 12:31:49.932177"], ["updated_at", "2018-05-25 12:31:49.932177"]]
Processing by UserActivitiesController#create as JSON
  ↳ app/controllers/user_activities_controller.rb:12
  Parameters: {"user_activity"=>{"activity_id"=>"3"}}
   (2.5ms)  COMMIT
  ↳ app/controllers/user_activities_controller.rb:12
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/
Completed 200 OK in 26ms (ActiveRecord: 11.9ms)


  User Load (2.9ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT $2  [["id", 2], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ /home/benjamin/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.0.rc1/lib/active_record/log_subscriber.rb:98
   (0.7ms)  BEGIN
  ↳ app/controllers/user_activities_controller.rb:12
  Activity Load (0.6ms)  SELECT  "activities".* FROM "activities" WHERE "activities"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 3], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/controllers/user_activities_controller.rb:12
  UserActivity Exists (0.9ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "user_activities" WHERE "user_activities"."user_id" = $1 AND "user_activities"."activity_id" = $2 LIMIT $3  [["user_id", 2], ["activity_id", 3], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/controllers/user_activities_controller.rb:12
   (0.3ms)  ROLLBACK
  ↳ app/controllers/user_activities_controller.rb:12
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/
Completed 200 OK in 19ms (ActiveRecord: 5.7ms)


Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-05-25 14:31:49 +0200
Processing by PagesController#home as HTML
```

The ROLLBACK is because i have mentionned uniqness in my model :)
The application start get / just after the post so the page is refresh to the / i don't know why

Thanks :)

Comment: Your AJAX request will not reload the page. If that is occurring, there must be something else in your logic which is causing it.

Comment: What is the error in Console? Check by preserving log if it is refreshing.

Comment: I put the logs in my post :)

Comment: can you also paste your controller code.

Comment: Thanks @sunny that was that line in my controller :     redirect_to root_path
...

Answer (score 0):

Did you forget to mention `dataType: "script"` with ajax request?

```
$('.newness').on('hover',function () {
  $(this).addClass('hover');
  var newnessId = $(this).data('id');
  $.ajax({
    url: '/user_activities', 
    method: 'POST', 
    data: {
      user_activity: {
        activity_id: newnessId
      }
    },
   dataType: "script"
  })
})
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer, still no working for me, i put the log in my post:)

Answer (score 0):

there is the answer :) 
in my controller i just remove

**redirect_to root_path**

```
class UserActivitiesController < ApplicationController

  def destroy
    @useractivity = UserActivity.find(params[:id])
    @useractivity.destroy
  end

  def create
    @user = current_user
    @useractivity = @user.user_activities.build(useractivities_params)
    @useractivity.save
  end

private

  def useractivities_params
    params.require(:user_activity).permit(:activity_id)
  end
end
```

Answer (score -1):

Sometime rails submit ajax request as HTML type then you need to specify the dataType, you can do that by passing dataType or as I do that.
You can try this like:

```
<script>
    $('.newness').hover(
        function () {
            $(this).addClass('hover');
           newnessId = $(this).data('id');
           $.ajax({url:'/user_activities.json', method: 'POST', data: {user_activity:{activity_id: newnessId}}})
        }
    )
</script>
```

Comment: Please take the time to describe what the issues are and why this solution helps. Remember, we're here to educate people, not just dump code on them.

Comment: Also - what did you change? I can't see it

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I have changed url type, please read this carefully.

Comment: Why would you do that? The OP has given no indication that the URL is wrong, nor that it needs an extension. That would also not affect the issue of an unexpected redirect happening. Please read the question carefully.

Comment: I have mentioned that

Comment: @Benjamin please try this then you will still got same issue then raise me.

Comment: Your description is non-sensical. Adding an extension to the URL does not set the datatype of the response - it' more likely to cause a 404 error. And again, does not address the issue of causing the page to redirect.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171757/discussion-between-sunny-and-rory-mccrossan).

Comment: Still not working, i have this just after the post in my log : Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-05-25 14:31:49 +0200